# How can I compare two List<Point> lists?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = new List<Point>();
    pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = pointsAffected.ToList();
    DrawIt = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1FileInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        DrawIt = true;
        trackBar1.Value = i;
        LoadPictureAt(trackBar1.Value, sender);
        pictureBox1.Load(trackBar1FileInfo[i].FullName);
        ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(trackBar1FileInfo[trackBar1.Value].FullName);
        ConvertedBmp.Save(ConvertedBmpDir + "\\ConvertedBmp.bmp");
        mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);
        scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);
        Button1Code();
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        newpixelscoordinates = pointsAffected.ToList();
    }
}
```

What I want to compare is in side the loop the List pixelscoordinatesinrectangle with the List newpixelscoordinates.

Both Lists are 
And both Lists contain pixels coordinates for example in one of the Lists index 0 
There is: x = 23 y = 56 and in the second List index 0: x = 456 y = 78

So I want to compare in each List index 0 against index 0 and index 1 against index 1.

The List that change each time in the loop is newpixelscoordinates.
Now in the loop the variable trackBar1FileInfo contain in this case 5000 items.
So there will be 5000 Lists to compare again pixelscoordinatesinrectangle.

Each itertion in the loop newpixelscoordinates will contain the same coordinates as pixelscoordinatesinrectangle or some of them different.

What I want to do is in one of the comparisons iterations if the Lists are not the same to write to a text file what indexes in both Lists was not the same.

If the Lists all indexes are the same just write to the text file that it was the same. For example if i = 345 then write to the text file i = 345 the same

And if not the same write more details:

i = 778
Index 45 not the same in both Lists
Index 787 not the same in both Lists

Comment: Your code snippet has _nothing_ to do with your description!

Comment: It seems that you have a pretty good understanding of what needs to be done. I'm not sure what the question is though. Are you having issues implementing this somewhere? Could you show how far you got and where you got stuck (try to keep it to a [sscce](http://sscce.org/))?

Comment: Google for examples of IEquatable<T>